# Is it correct to say "the Lego got broken apart"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

You're holding a Lego as shown in the above picture.

But because the Lego is of poor quality, the blocks did not stick together and while you were holding the Lego, somehow it got separated as shown in the below picture.

[image]

Is it correct to say "**the Lego got broken apart**"?

The verb "**break**" is too much. It was just that the Lego blocks got separated. And a child may not understand the word "**separated**"

Comment: You could say "the Legos came apart" -- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/come-apart

Comment: Or 'The blocks came apart'.

Comment: In British English, "the Legos" is considered ungrammatical; "Lego" is a mass noun in BrE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is correct to say "The Lego got broken apart." You could also say "The Lego broke apart." Either way is correct. As suggested in the comments, it is also correct to say "The Lego came apart." I agree that "separated" may be too a big word for a young child.